# Regular expression: ignore all style inside a html content except img's by javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have those regex for ignore all style attribute. It works. But now I must show images inside html and don't remove style. I couldn't write regex in this case. Can you give any advice solve that problem.

```
var test = "<a href='#' style='border:1px solid red;'>dasda</a><img style='border:1px solid red;' />";
var rex = /\s+style\s*=\s*(\"|\').*?(\"|\')/igm
str = test.replace(rex, '');
```

**EDIT**

I know how to use selectors. 'test' is not 'DOM' element. This operation works inside fully javascript . 'test' is just any text. on every occasion I check the text is simple text or not . if not maybe it html and if it is any html code I will clear that( as converting to simple string )

Comment: Don't do this. Work with the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to match all  the style attributes except the one within `<img>` tag.

```
> var text = "<a href='#' style='border:1px solid red;'>dasda</a><img style='border:1px solid red;' />"
> var str = text.replace(/(?!<img[*<>]*)(<[^<>]*)\s+style\s*=\s*['"].*?["']/g, "$1")
undefined
> console.log(str)
<a href='#'>dasda</a><img style='border:1px solid red;' />
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/10)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a separate CSS stylesheet with [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to apply styles only to the `<img>` elements that you need (depending on the case you can use tag selectors or apply a class to them and use the class selector).

Comment: Oh, all right, I didn't see the edited post so I thought you meant something else :) Glad you found an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use RegExp at all for this. Assuming the html snippet is safe, you might try something like this:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
var html='<a style="color: blue;" href="about:blank"><img style="border: 1px solid blue;" src="someting.jpg"></a>';
doc.body.innerHTML=html;
var nodes=Array.prototype.slice.call(doc.querySelectorAll("[style]")||[]);
nodes.forEach(function(node){
  if(node.tagName.toLowerCase()=="img")return;
  node.removeAttribute("style");
})
doc.body.innerHTML;

/*
result:
<a href="about:blank"><img style="border: 1px solid blue;" src="someting.jpg"></a>
*/
```

It's just easier to let the browser do the heavy work parsing HTML, then doing DOM manipulations.